# Why Gaussian process is not Ergodic in general?

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

Can anyone use a simple way to explain this? I heard this in class but I do not know why.

---

By Wiki: a random process is ergodic if its statistical properties can be deduced from a 
         single, sufficiently long sample of the process.

Our note: A random process is ergodic if for all invariant event F, after time shift, either P(F) = 1 or P(F) = 0.

---

I have difficulty to explain the why through the def. of WIKI or our note.

Thanks

Comment: @ sleeve chen : your lecture definition is the mathematically right formulation of ergodocity. The wiki one is an heuristic approach to ergodicity and not a very formal one (what does it mean precisely "irs statistical properties" ?) nonetheless I believe that it is intuitively correct, but to get it you have to see how from the formal defninition (and extra hypothesis) you can derive the "statistical properties" of a process. Best regards.